# When using document.getElementById, it's not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

**The Problem**
I'm trying to display the output of a function to a div, but i can't figure out why it isn't displaying. How can i fix this so that it displays properly?

**What i've tried so far**
I've copied a document.getElementById statement from another codeblock i wrote that is functioning , and checked it for any typos etc.  All seems well there. 
I googled innerHTML to be sure that I was using it correctly.
Also changed the document.etc line to document.write to ensure the function was working properly, it output properly.

**My Code**

```
<html>
<head>    
<script type="text/javascript">
    function parameters(one, two) {
        document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=(one + two);
    }

    parameters("coding" , "coffee");
</script>
</head>    
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it's working for me?  unless i don't understand your problem?  https://jsfiddle.net/zwcmbtt0/

Comment: I'm using notepad++ to edit and test it, and when i click run in chrome, nothing appears.

Comment: You are trying to reference an element before it exists. Pretty simple to spot and the console will tell you that with an error message that is certainly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use the `div#output` before it's even loaded by the browser.

There are two simple solutions for this:

#### First

Put the `<script>` tag after the `div#output`, so it will be already loaded.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function parameters(one, two) {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=(one + two);
    }

    parameters("coding" , "coffee");
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Second

Put your Javascript code inside the `DOMContentLoaded` event, so it will only be called after all the DOMElements are loaded in your page.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function parameters(one, two) {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML=(one + two);
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      parameters("coding" , "coffee");
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, that clarifies things.  Lesson learnt, can't run what's not loaded yet.

Comment: @NewCoder101 if my answer was useful for you, please click on the arrow to upvote it, and on the `V` to mark it as accepted!

Comment: Upvoted, and can't accept for another four minutes, but i appreciate everyones time, thanks for clearing it up, i would never have thought about it not actually being loaded yet.